# How to pipe an object in the powershell correctly to avoid "Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline" error

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there any way to do the following without creating the object $obj?

```
$obj = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Students") ; $obj.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
```

I have tried to pipe, like this:

```
New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Students") | $_.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
```

but got following error:

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:128
+ New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Students") | $_.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifi
er]).Value <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Students")).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick to using the pipeline, use the ForEach-Object cmdlet.

```
 New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Students") | ForEach-Object {

    $_.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value)
}
```